# Why is this whatsapp question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic, close-reasons

[Delete messages after hours WhatsApp](https://superuser.com/q/1725257/325613)

why is this off topic?

question text is

> How can I delete messages for everyone after several hours in WhatsApp?

Answer (score 4):

Whatsapp is, broadly speaking, a web service.

Whether a web service has a particular feature natively and independent from your client is off topic on Super User per [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) page:

> **not about …**
>
> websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,

There *may* be desktop clients for Whatsapp that do support deleting messages and whether they allow deletion after a particular time is a something you should first check for in your clients documentation.

When asking for help with client applications you should be specific and tell us what client you are using. Only "desktop" clients are on topic at Super User so your question would have to be about the client and not the broader web service.  "How do I use <this client feature> to achieve X?" would be on topic here. "Does this feature exist in Whatsapp?" implies the entire ecosystem and is both too broad and about the service rather than any specific application.

Other places to look, depending on your question focus:

- The [Whatsapp Web Client](https://web.whatsapp.com/) belongs at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)
- The Android Client belongs at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- IPhone or Mac Clients belong at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)
- Linux clients may belong at either [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/)
- Windows Clients belong at [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

In all cases you should have a good idea that your requirement is something that *should* be available in the client to begin with. You should be able to demonstrate a minimum level of research and awareness that the feature is there, but that you are having trouble using or accessing it.

If your question is specific to the underlying web service then you may be better off [contacting Whatsapp Support](https://www.whatsapp.com/contact/).

Comment: Your second last paragraph is helpful. I didn't know hacking or non-official client solutions were off topic here.

Comment: @theonlygusti  It's not about "hacking" or being non-official, it's about knowing that feature *should* be available in the first place.  Your question is vague, has no information on what client you are using, and shows no personal effort or research indicating that this should be possible.